# React & Axios - Dynamically add key and value to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on a little project of mine and ran into an issue.
I am using the "ASOS" API and I need to dynamically add key and value to the parameters that it needs to find the correct product. It is to pick for example color, size, price range etc. Issue is, all things I've tried haven't ended up in a success.

How do I dynamically add key and value to an object?

Something like this:

```
currency: "USD",
sizeSchema: "US",
lang: "en-US",
newKey: newValue
```

Here is my code:

```
const FetchAPI = (props) => {
  const [product, setProducts] = useState([]);
  // Key and Value
  let facetKey = props.facetKey;
  let facetValue = props.facetValue;

// Sets the paramaters
  let params = {
    store: "US",
    offset: props.offset,
    categoryId: props.categoryId,
    limit: props.limit,
    country: "US",
    sort: "freshness",
    currency: "USD",
    sizeSchema: "US",
    lang: "en-US",
  };
  // Need to add my "facetKey" and "facetValue" to "params".

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://asos2.p.rapidapi.com/products/v2/list",
      params: params,
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "",
      },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        setProducts(response.data.products);
        props.items(response.data.itemCount);
        props.facets(response.data.facets);
        console.log(response.data.facets);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, [props.offset, props.limit]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {product.map((product) => (
          <ProductCard
            key={product.id}
            img={product.imageUrl}
            name={product.name}
            price={product.price.current.text}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks!

**Keep in mind**
The `facetKey` and `facetValue` return string values, and if the user havent picked a "facet", or an option to filter the products. Then it returns `undefined`, can of course change this to null.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `[]` operator with objects.

In general:

```js
let obj = {};
let key = 'x';
let value = 3;

obj[key] = value;
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj[key]);
```

In your example:

```
let facetKey = props.facetKey;
let facetValue = props.facetValue;

// Sets the paramaters
let params = {
  // ...
};
// Need to add my "facetKey" and "facetValue" to "params".

if (facetKey)
  params[facetKey] = facetValue;
```

Comment: Ahh okay, I see. Yea that works! Now it just has to refresh the products, would adding `params` to the `[]` in useEffect work or would it be simpler with a page reload?

Comment: I think you're asking how to update `params` before it's used in `useEffect()`? If so, your snippet doesn't show `facetKey` and `facetValue` being changed, but assuming it's changed in your full code, then yes you can just move the `params[k] = v` to inside `useEffect()`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. That works flawlessly! Just need it to be able to filter multiple facey keys and values. I know that I need to use `...` so far, but where it shall be I don't know! haha, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code as follows.

```
let params = {
    store: "US",
    offset: props.offset,
    categoryId: props.categoryId,
    limit: props.limit,
    country: "US",
    sort: "freshness",
    currency: "USD",
    sizeSchema: "US",
    lang: "en-US",
    [facetKey]: facetValue
};
```

And if facetKey can be undefined, you can do like this.

```
let params = {
    store: "US",
    offset: props.offset,
    categoryId: props.categoryId,
    limit: props.limit,
    country: "US",
    sort: "freshness",
    currency: "USD",
    sizeSchema: "US",
    lang: "en-US",
};

facetKey && params = { ...params, [facetKey]: facetValue }
// or
if (facetKey) {
    params = { ...params, [facetKey]: facetValue }
}
```